# Custom function with Ajax not working as expected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am bashing my head with this problem whole day. I lack good knowledge of JavaScript, and for DOM manipulation i started to use jQuery. It is easy to construct some basic things. What i wanted is to build custom function that will populate  form with list that will be pulled out of database based on input parameters that i pass to this function.

The code would look like this:

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.multiSelect = function(a,b,c) {
        var someVar1 = parseInt(a,10);
        var someVar2 = parseInt(b,10);
        var someVar3 = c;
        var dataString = "a=" + someVar1 + "&b=" + someVar2 + "&c=" + someVar3;
        $.ajax({
            type:       "POST",
            url:        "test_ajax.php",
            data:       dataString,
            dataType:   'json',
            success:    function(data) {
                var a1 = data['a'];
                var b1 = data['b'];
                var c1 = data['c'];
                return $(this).html('<p>' + a1 + b1 + c1 + '</p>');
            }
        });
        return $(this).html('<p>' + someVar1 + someVar2 + someVar3 + '</p>');
    }
    };
}) (jQuery);
```

And PHP code inside test_ajax.php, is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['a']) AND !empty($_POST['a'])) {
    $_something = array(
                    'a'=> $_POST['a'],
                    'b'=> $_POST['b'],
                    'c'=> $_POST['b']
                    );
    echo json_encode($_something);
}
?>
```

Now when i use my jQuery function like this:

```
$('#someDiv').multiSelect(1,1,'user');
```

Function in side $.(ajax), returns nothing, and outside of it (that i created just to see what is passed in to the function) returns "11user".

And if I use above code like this:

```
$(function() {
    var dataString = 'a=' + 1 + '&b=' + 1 + '&c=user';
    $.ajax({
            type:       "POST",
            url:        "test_ajax.php",
            data:       dataString,
            dataType:   'json',
            success:    function(data) {
                var a1 = data['a'];
                var b1 = data['b'];
                var c1 = data['c'];
                $('#someDiv').html('<p>' + a1 + b1 + c1 + '</p>');
            }
        });
});
```

It fetches data from test_ajax.php script. All of this is simple just to troubleshoot problem, then i am going to build complex PHP script that will do it's job with database.

I am guessing that i am doing something wrong with variables (local/global) or incorrect jQuery function chaining.

EDIT: Since i would repeat this operation many times on different menus, function makes more logic then repeating whole code over and over.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're saying is that this line inside your `$.ajax` call doesn't work:

```
return $(this).html('<p>' + a1 + b1 + c1 + '</p>');
```

This is because `this`, within the `success` call, does not point to the DOM object. It points to an object that contains the settings for the AJAX call.

You need to use the `context` property in your AJAX call to make `this` mean what you want it to mean:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:       "POST",
        url:        "test_ajax.php",
        data:       dataString,
        dataType:   'json',
        context:    this,
        success:    function(data) {
            var a1 = data['a'];
            var b1 = data['b'];
            var c1 = data['c'];
            return $(this).html('<p>' + a1 + b1 + c1 + '</p>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you guys (there was another post with same answer) it worked like a charm ;)